# How can I detect if a screen is connected?

Tags: android, android-screen

I am trying to detect if a display/screen/tv is connected to my mini pc running Android 4.1 and if it is even turned on, so my app only shows and updates with information from the net if someone is able to watch it.

The mini pc has an HDMI connection and no other display.
I already tried to use the Sony HDMI intent described here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/29/how-to-use-the-hidden-hdmi-api-tutorial/
And I couldn't get the "hidden" hdmi intent to work.

The displaymanager seems to at least send some messages to logcat if the display is turned of or the cable is unplugged.

Any help or hints appreciated.

Edit: Cleared up the question

Answer (score -2):

onStop and onStart should indicate it, wether there is a screen connected and turned on or not:

so in your current Activity:

```
protected void onStart() {
   //screen is connected and turned ON
} 

protected void onStop() {
   //screen is disconnected or turned OFF
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work how i need it to.
My app is supposed to be running without user interaction and polling data from the net and showing some gui on the screen/display/monitor/TV.
You plug the mini pc in, start the app and off you go.

If a user unplugs the HDMI cable or turns of the screen/display/monitor/tv i want to notice this so i can stop pulling data from the net and log the time.

onStop() and onStart() only detects if the app is pushed to the background, not if the external display itself is unplugged/turned off.

Comment: Yes, you can't use this solution now, because your application isn't running in the foreground.